# Find all integer solutions of $x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x +5 = y^2$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Find all integer solutions to $x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x +5 = y^2$.

I'm in a dead end. I've transformed the expression in the following state: 
$(x^2+1)(x+1)^2 = y^2 -4$

I couldn't see anyway in which I could work with this expression in this state, so I continued into writing $(x^2+x+2)^2 - y^2 = 4x(x+1)$. Now I'm trying to use mod 8 and trying with different modulo. Please suggestions?

not entire solution tho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(x^2+x)^2 < y^2 < (x^2+x+1)^2$.

Comment: The second inequality doesn't hold... You get $(x^2 + x + 1)^2 = x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1 = y - 4 + x^2$ but $-4+x^2 > 0$ doesn't hold for $|x| \le 2$. Consider adding this in your hint.